# htaccess on multilingual site works instead of index file. How to fix this?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to make a multilingual page, and for now I can do this

```
domain.com/LANGUAGE/page-name
```

and it works.

The problem is that if I want to be in the index file with a language like

```
domain.com/LANGUAGE
```

I get a 404 error.

How can I do this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.*)?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It is unclear what really is being asked here. How should `domain.com/LANGUAGE` be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Should not your last line be

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

This way any requests having only the language path will go to index.php

or just make a new rule where the path after the language does not exist

```
RewriteRule ^(en|el)(/)?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```